# Can Typescript guard / discriminate based on field presence (undefined / absent) rather than value?

Tags: typescript, undefined, discriminated-union, union-types, type-narrowing

Can anyone explain why Typescript can narrow types with the `in` keyword, but not by presence an non-undefined value? I'm porting a large codebase from JS to TS, and very extensive use has been made of the `if (x.something) { ... }` construct.

```
declare const x: { a?: object } | { b: number };

if ('a' in x) { 
  const Q = x.a;  // Q: object | undefined, correct but not very helpful - still have to test Q for non-undefined
}

if (x.a) { 
  const Q = x.a; // Doesn't work, but if it did, Q: object, which is helpful
}

if (typeof x.a !== "undefined") { 
  const Q = x.a; // Same as above
}
```

Note that if it's not a union, it works as expected:

```
declare const x: { a?: object }

if ('a' in x) { 
  const Q = x.a;  // Q: object | undefined, correct but not very helpful
}

if (x.a) { 
  const Q = x.a; // Q: object (yay!)
}
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

**The problem**

There are a few rules to keep in mind:

- **You are allowed to read only the properties that exist on every member of the union.** That's why `if (x.a)` errors — `a` is not defined on the second member of your union.
- **Object types are allowed to have excess properties.** TypeScript uses structural typing. This means that a type `{ foo: string, bar: number }` is, in general, assignable to type `{ foo: string }`. That's why `if ('a' in x)` doesn't work — any type with a property called `a` would pass that check. We have no guarantee that the value will be an object, though. It's not safe to assume it.
- In order to disjoin unions, **prefer user-defined type guards over inline checks** like `typeof x === "string"`. Type guards have a special syntax that tells TypeScript to narrow the checked type. That's why `if (typeof x.a !== "undefined")` doesn't work in your example.

**The solution**

Make your union exclusive. Tell TypeScript that if `a` exists, then `b` will never be defined, and vice versa.

```
declare const x: { a?: object, b?: undefined } | { b: number, a?: undefined }
```

Note that we're marking the unwanted properties as optional. If instead we did `{ a?: object, b?: undefined } | { b: number, a?: undefined }`, then the unwanted properties would be required, and `x` would have to have them set explicitly to `undefined`.

You can now use these methods to work with `x`.

```
function isDefined<T>(candidate: T | null | undefined): candidate is T {
  return candidate != null;
}

if (x.a) { 
  const Q = x.a; // object
}

if (isDefined(x.a)) {
  const Q = x.a; // object
}

if (typeof x.a !== "undefined") { 
  const Q = x.a; // object
}
```

Note that you still cannot use the method using the `in` operator. There is a good reason for that: it prevents false positives. Our unwanted properties are allowed to exist on the object for as long as their value is explicitly set to `undefined`. Consider the following example:

```
function test(x: { a?: object, b?: undefined } | { b: number, a?: undefined }): void {
  if ('a' in x) {
    x.a; // object | undefined (good). We cannot expect object here.
  }
}

test({ b: 1, a: undefined }); // "a" is not an object!
```

**Tip: use `ExclusiveUnion` helper**

Instead of marking the unwanted properties as `?undefined`, we can create a helper to do that for us.

```
declare const x: ExclusiveUnion<{ a?: object } | { b: number }>;
```

Implementation:

```
type DistributedKeyOf<T> =
  T extends any
    ? keyof T
    : never;

type CreateExclusiveUnion<T, U = T> =
  T extends any
    ? T & Partial<Record<Exclude<DistributedKeyOf<U>, keyof T>, never>>
    : never;

type ExclusiveUnion<T> = CreateExclusiveUnion<T>;
```

Comment: Great answer - thank you for the detailed explanation. I think the "excess properties" bit is where I had forgotten why it doesn't work, and the solution of creating a union with common fields for the discriminator to examine is very elegant, and in my case ideal because it's for the TS modifications and doesn't involve extensive modification to the existing JS.

Selected as the best answer. Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

Can you use a custom type check?
For example:

```
export const instanceOfIImportNotification = (_o: any): _o is IImportNotification => {
  return 'metaData' in _o && 'importType' in _o.metaData && 'azureFilePath' in _o.metaData;
};
```

Comment: You can do this, but it means modifying a lot of existing code, so I may as well use `in` rather than some other function. This solution doesn't explain the issue, it just describes a different way of avoiding it