# How to discriminate an union against "never" type?

Tags: typescript, discriminated-union, typescript-never

Let's say I have this union:

```
type TShape = {
    id: string;
}

type TCircle = TShape & {
    radius: number;
    size: never;
}

type TSquare = TShape & {
    radius: never;
    size: number;
}
```

The problem is how to discriminate the two possible types (in this case) using the `radius` field, for instance:

```
function getArea(shape: TCircle | TSquare): number {
    if (typeof shape.radius === "number") {
        return shape.radius * shape.radius * Math.PI;
    }
    else {
        return shape.radius * shape.size;  //no error?
    }
}
```

What I expect is a compiler error on the last calculation, because the `radius` field never exist on the `TSquare` type.

What's wrong with this and how to solve this problem?

Comment: This is not what `never` means. `TSquare` having a `never` field means "you can `never` make a `TSquare` (since you can `never` fill in its required property `radius`)", not "`TSquare` 'never' contains `radius`." [This answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/62140006/5684257) suggests using `radius?: undefined`.

Comment: @HTNW the suggestion works fine. Back to the "never", your explaination depicts an assertive usage of "never" and that's fine to me. However, why the compiler shouldn't infer the type from that assertion?

Comment: Please see [docs](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/basic-types.html#never). `The never type is a subtype of, and assignable to, every type`

Comment: Now I understand what you mean, but the conclusion is: it does not seem possible to discriminate an union by the presence or not of a field. The optional "undefined" of the answer apparently works, but it actually does not.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since TSquare does not need radius field you can declare it without it

```
type TSquare = TShape & {
    size: number;
}
```

Then you can modify function and check if radius is defined.

```
function getArea(shape: TCircle | TSquare): number {
    if ("radius" in shape) {
        return shape.radius * shape.radius * Math.PI;
    }
    else {
        return shape.radius * shape.size;  // this should be an error this time
    }
}
```

Comment: That's good! unfortunately I already patched my code to avoid the problem, but I guess it should have worked this way. I totally forgot this usage of the "in" operator. Great!